# the difference between shallowReactive and shallowRef in vue3?

Tags: vuejs3

the difference between shallowReactive  and shallowRef in vue3? what the shallowRef can do the shallowReactive can not do?

shallowReactive is always used for object,why need shallowRef for object.

Comment: https://v3.vuejs.org/api/basic-reactivity.html#shallowreadonly, maybe you can find what do you want in this link

Answer (score 16):

`ref` is for tracking a single value whereas `reactive` is for tracking an object or array. The implication on this on the `shallow` versions is that `shallowRef` will only trigger a listener if the `value` itself changes, and `shallowReactive` will only trigger on the first level of values (so the direct keys)

here is an example that I hope illustrates the differences between the behaviour.

The reactive change on `reactive` and `shallowReacive` can be observed with a `watch`

`ref` and `shallowRef` behave the same way when it comes to using a `watch`, but the object is reactive on a deep change in the template.

```js
const s1 = Vue.shallowRef({ x: 1, y: { a: 1 } });
const r1 = Vue.ref({ x: 1, y: { a: 1 } });
const s2 = Vue.shallowReactive({ x: 1, y: { a: 1 } });
const r2 = Vue.reactive({ x: 1, y: { a: 1 } });

Vue.watch(r1, () => console.log("ref (obj) changed"));
Vue.watch(s1, () => console.log("shallowRef (obj) changed"));
Vue.watch(s2, () => console.log("shallowReactive changed"));
Vue.watch(r2, () => console.log("reactive changed"));

setTimeout(() => {
  console.log("=== update shallow object ===");
  r1.value.x = 2;
  s1.value.x = 2;
  s2.x = 2;
  r2.x = 2;
}, 1000);

setTimeout(() => {
  console.log("=== update nested y.a values ===");
  r1.value.y.a = 2;
  s1.value.y.a = 2;
  s2.y.a = 2;
  r2.y.a = 2;
}, 2000);

var app1 = Vue.createApp({
  data() {
    return { r1 };
  },
}).mount("#app1");

var app2 = Vue.createApp({
  data() {
    return { s1 };
  },
}).mount("#app2");
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3.0.5/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>

<div id="app1">
  <pre>ref:     {{JSON.stringify(r1, null, 0)}}</pre>
</div>

<div id="app2">
  <pre>shallow: {{JSON.stringify(s1, null, 0)}}</pre>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

The difference between a `shallowRef` and `shallowReactive` is that a shallowReactive will still unwrap refs at the root level, while a shallowRef will not.

```js
const myRef = shallowRef({name: 'Paul', more: {}})
const myReactive = shallowReactive({name: 'Paul', more: {}})
const age = ref(21)

myRef.value.age = age // will not unwrap
myRef.value.more.age = age // will not unwrap
myReactive.age = age // WILL unwrap
myReactive.more.age = age // will not unwrap

console.log(myRef.value.age.value) // value is not unwrapped
console.log(myRef.value.more.age.value) // value is not unwrapped
console.log(myReactive.age) // value IS unwrapped (root level reactive property)
console.log(myReactive.more.age.value) // // value is not unwrapped
```

## Additional Information For The Curious

### Part 1: Simple Difference Between Ref and Reactive

The main differences between ref and reactive in Vue are

- A ref can be replaced by another value.
- A ref can hold a primitive type.
- ref values must be accessed using their value property.

Under the hood, a ref is just a box that holds a reactive value.  Because of this box, the value needs to be accessed via its 'value' property.  This box allows the entire value to be replaced.

### Part 2: What Is Shallow

By default, both refs and reactive will not contain any nested refs.  Any refs added to them will be unwrapped; Added refs will still remain reactive because as stated, they will still be a part of a parent reactive value, whether it is a ref or reactive value.

A shallowRef or shallowReactive will not unwrap nested refs. But as stated, shallowReactive will still unwrap top level refs.